# Best way to Initializing data members of a class using constructor in C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I know below three styles of initializing data members of a c++ class. But which one is safer and recommended to use. Kindly tell me **why**?

**Style-1**

```
    class example{
        int var1 = 0;
        double *var2 = NULL;
        
        example()
        {}
    };
```

**Style-2**

```
    class example{
        int var1;
        double *var2;
        
        example()
        {
            var1 = 0;
            var2 = NULL;
        }
    };
```

**Style-3**

```
    class example{
        int var1;
        double *var2;
        
        example():var1(0),var2(NULL)
        {}
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer right as for a "best practices" question like this, you will always get several opinions.

I would recommend to follow the C++ Core Guidelines when unsure what is a best practice. Regarding your topic see [C.48](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-in-class-initializer) and [C.49](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c49-prefer-initialization-to-assignment-in-constructors):

1. Prefer Style 1 over Styles 2,3
2. Prefer Style 3 over Style 2

To shortly recap the reasoning from my perspective:

1. Style 1 allows to use default constructors (not implementing a constructor, but still getting initialization)
2. Style 1 allows the reader of the header to see the defaults
3. With style 1, you only need to look at one place to ensure a variable is properly initialized and you cannot "forget" to initialize a variable in one of your constructors
4. Style 3 ist still needed when arguments are used to initialize variables. It is still to be preferred over style 2 as "initialization" of a variable is clearly communicated through initialization, at the expected position in the code, instead of being slightly obscured as an assignment operation that might be buried within the constructor code

Comment: Also worth noting is that style 1 was not supported before C++11 (which shouldn't be an issue anymore). And in style 2 your actually have an extra copy.